# I don't want to send stack trace errors in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I'm building a Rails 5 API and trying to handle the error response when a record is not found (i.e. `/v1/users/99` but that user does not exist).

I'm using Active Model Serializer for serialization and I'm thinking there must be a way to only show the status and the error, not the stack trace. Right now, I get this:

```
{
status: 404,
error: "Not Found",
exception: "#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=99>",
traces: {
Application Trace: [
{
id: 1,
trace: "app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:45:in `set_user'"
}
],
Framework Trace: [
{
id: 0,
trace: "activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/core.rb:173:in `find'"
},
{
id: 2,
trace: "activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'"
},
{
id: 3,
trace: "activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'"
},
{
id: 4,
trace: "actionpack (5.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'"
},
{
id: 5,
trace: "activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'"
    },
.
.
.
```

I want the error to simple on the API side, just status and error. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been doing this for logging and printing different messages in different environments.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found_rescue

  def record_not_found_rescue(exception)
    logger.info("#{exception.class}: " + exception.message)
    if Rails.env.production?
      render json: {}, status: :not_found
    else
      render json: { message: exception, backtrace: exception.backtrace }, status: :not_found
    end
  end
end
```

I found this to be useful not only to not print back traces but you now don't need an if statement in every single controller action.

It couples well with finder methods in your controller.

```
  def show
    user = find_user

    render json: user , status: :ok
  end

  private
    def find_user
      User.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Remember you can handle different types of exceptions like this, not only the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I edited the json response a bit just to show the status and error on prod but seems very flexible to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
begin
  user = User.find(params[:id])
rescue 
  render json: 'no user found', status: 404
end

render json: user, status: 200
```

OR you can handle exception in all controller using common handler

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  around_action :handle_exceptions
  def handle_exceptions
    begin
      yield
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      status = 404
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
      status = 403
    rescue Exception => e
      status = 500
    end
    handle_error "#{e.message}", status unless e.class == NilClass
  end

  def handle_error(message, status = 500)
    message = message.is_a?(Array) ? message.join('. ') : message
    @errors = { message: message, status: status }
    render json: @errors, :status => status
  end
end

In your controller no need to write rescue, Just find the record
user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: That certainly helps! I'm wondering if there's anyway to keep things in the serializer? Or maybe at the point of `render json: 'no user found', status: 404` I could invoke the response with AMS. Either way it's good to know that I can go with this.

Comment: In your code you will face double render error if any error occurred.

Comment: Where, you find double render error? FYI first part and second part is different

Comment: If user not present in rescue block one render and after rescue block another render. It will through double render error